# Fetching / Getting the id of a subcommand in a subcommandgroup (DiscordJS v14)

Tags: discord.js

So im trying to make a fully dynamic help embed which shows each command with their description.
I need the id to make the commands clickable (like this: </commandname:831874384724> ) all the "normal" commands are shown as they should. But 2 commands, those with subcommandgroups are not clickable. So back to the question does anyone know how to fetch the command ids i read through the docs but didnt find anything regarding ids in subcommands.

Edit: Problem Solved, subcommandgroup name and subcommandname must be written too so it looks like this : </commandname subcommandgroup subcommand:commandid>

Comment: _"how to fetch the command ids"_ Global or guild commands?

Comment: global commands

Comment: If you can, it might be helpful to add your solution as an answer to this post and mark it as solved. That way, other people can find it in the future!